# How to do fast controller initialization

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

In my application with GetX, I had to create around 7 controllers, and they need to be initialized.
Everything works fine, but the controller I created for mobile ads sometimes throws an error. Actually, it does not give an error, but a bug occurs.

The problem is that when the app opens, it needs to show ads on the first click. As soon as the application is opened, when you click quickly, it does not show the interstitial ad. But a few seconds pass and if clicked, it shows the ad.

I'm not writing here because I don't have a problem with the codes. Is there any method I can solve this?

Comment: await until the ad has been loaded correctly.

Comment: How i can do this? I only use: AdController adController = Get.put(AdController());

Comment: You have to post some of the code inside AdController, then we can know how you can await it.